# How to analyze the latencies (application latency and rtt) of various applications in a citrix receiver?

Tags: networking, ubuntu-14.04, citrix, ntop

Ntopng can identify the citrix flows but I am not able to see the information about the different applications running inside Citrix receiver.

I am using Ntopng on ubuntu 14.04.